# How to take time into account for linear mixed model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear-model

I am working with data consisting of concentrations of different metabolites taken from different subjects at different time points. I want to find out the relationship between **Metabolite A** specifically and **Metabolite B**, **Metabolite C**, **Metabolite D** and so on, to see if there are any metabolites that can be used to predict the levels of Metabolite A.

My model would look something like this:

`MetaboliteA ~ MetaboliteB + MetaboliteC + MetaboliteD + (1 | ID)`

where **ID** is the subject ID as a random variable to take into account the different subjects.

However, I also have a **Time** variable which I am unsure how to incorporate into the model. I have 4 time points and they are the same for all subjects.

To be clear, I am not interested in how the metabolite levels are affected by time; I just want the change in metabolite levels over time to be taken into account in my model. Basically I am not interested in the result from having Time as a fixed effect, but it feels wrong to just ignore it in the model.

My thoughts are to maybe use Time as a random slope, but I am unsure if this is the best way to do it. Also, if this is the best way to do it, I have heard that any variable you have as a random slope also needs to be a fixed variable. Is this right?

Comment: IMO you should include Time as a fixed effect. I don't think it makes sense to add Time as a random slope.

Comment: Could you expand on your "to be clear" paragraph in telling more about what question you have that can be answered with respect to time?

Comment: How many different values of `Time` do you have per individual? Are those the same `Time` values for all individuals, or do the `Time` values differ among individuals? Please provide extra information in response to this and other comments by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some function of `Time` as a predictor in your model would account for time-related changes in `MetaboliteA` *beyond* what you would predict based on the *simultaneously measured* values of `MetaboliteB`, `MetaboliteC`, and `MetaboliteD`. There thus isn't a general answer to your question. You have to apply your understanding of the subject matter to choose how to include `Time`.

If you think that the level of `MetaboliteA` has no association with `Time` *per se* beyond its association with simultaneous levels of the other metabolites, you might be able to treat the 4 time points as repeated measurements and ignore `Time` completely. Otherwise, include `Time` in some form as  a fixed effect, as Adrià Luz says in a comment.

If you treat `Time` as a numeric variable and add a single `Time` term to your model, you implicitly assume that the level of `MetaboliteA` (*beyond* what's associated with the other Metabolites) changes linearly with `Time`.* Is that a reasonable assumption?

If you can't assume that linearity, you might treat `Time` as a 4-level categorical predictor. That allows for systematic changes in the baseline level of `MetaboliteA` (again, *beyond* what's associated with the other Metabolites) without imposing any particular functional form. The downside is that your model now includes even more coefficients to estimate.

For more general considerations in this type of study, see Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long). For example, this situation might be handled with a multivariate linear model or via generalized least squares rather than with a mixed model.

Another issue to consider is whether the association of `MetaboliteA` with `MetaboliteB`, `MetaboliteC`, and `MetaboliteD` depends only on the *current* levels of those metabolites. That's the implicit assumption of your model. Sometimes such associations depend on the *history* of the levels. Again, whether or how to model that depends on your understanding of the subject matter.

---

*That would also be the assumption underlying simple random slopes among individuals for `Time`. Random slopes are typically modeled as a zero-mean Gaussian distribution around a fixed-effect slope, so with that type of model `Time` would also be a fixed effect. That's similar to random intercepts, which are modeled as a zero-mean Gaussian distribution around the overall model (fixed-effect) intercept. From your description of the experimental design, I'm not sure you have enough data to fit a random-slope model adequately, even if linearity in time holds.